# Is there any way to get status of view render in backbone marionette composite or itemview?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How we can track the status of view render in backbone marionette.

for example view need to fetch some data from server to render it.

```
App.main.currentView.ChatContactRegion.show(new ChatContactsView());
```

Here how I can check, whether view rendered successfully to given region? Is there any callback for **show** function?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: not enough information to understand what you want to do, or why. please update the question with more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A region manager will raise a few events during it's showing and closing of views:

So, in your example, the `ChatContactsView` instance passed to `show()` will have an `onShow` event triggered.

You can hook into that event in your `ChatContactsView` class definition:

```
ChatContactsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  onShow: function(){
    // called when the view has been shown
  }
});
```

More detail in the [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#region-events-and-callbacks)